# ASP.NET MVC - 406 Not Acceptable on return View()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out why I'm getting the 406 Not Acceptable error code with a simple .NET Core Application I've put together.

This is the HTTP Request that is calling the code:

```
POST /my HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44350
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: text/html, text/plain, */*
Connection: close
Referer: https://localhost:44350/fetch-data
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 35

{ "searchTerm" :  "cookie",
 }
```

This is the HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 09 May 2020 17:46:38 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

The Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace test_dotnet_angular.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Produces("text/html")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public MyController()
        { }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Post([FromBody] My data)
        {
            ViewBag.SearchTerm = data.searchTerm;
            return View("View");

        }
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
using System;

namespace test_dotnet_angular
{
    public class My
    {
        public string searchTerm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Search Results";
    ViewData["Content-Type"] = "text/html";
}

<h1>Search Results</h1>
You searched for @ViewBag.SearchTerm
```

I know I must be missing something stupid. I'm brand new to .NET. I've done a lot of searching, but almost everything is about JSON return types. All the examples I find on returning view results seem to look like what I'm doing. I don't understand what small detail I must be missing.

Comment: what version of .net core are you using?

Comment: you have a request header `Accept: application/json, text/plain` whereas in the controller, it says `text/html` in the `Produces` attribute

Comment: @YegorAndrosov 3.1

Comment: @Saravanan with the wildcard at the end, I think it would normally handle it; but just to be sure I tried manually changing it to text/html and it still behaves the same. I'll update the example to match, since I'm sure that does look weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma in the JSON makes ASP.NET Core MVC return 406 Not Acceptable.

This is not working:

```
{ 
    "searchTerm" :  "cookie",
}
```

This is working:

```
{ 
    "searchTerm" :  "cookie"
}
```

Comment: Wow. I knew it was something simple. Thank-you! As soon as it lets me, I will accept this answer. I can't believe that made the difference for this error.

Comment: That's weird behavior of Core MVC !