# Not Acceptable Response(406) Message Asp.NET Code Web API (C#) - .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

Normally I use Ok() to return the 200OK message form a API controller. Also NotFound() and NoContent(). But I could not find something like Acceptable Response(406). So, my question is is it possible to return Acceptable Response(406) from API controller without using HttpResponseMessage.

I know I can use something like HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable) but I want to know if there is a better approach which covers all the status codes and a custom error message can be returned. Reason why I am trying to find another way is because in postman It shows wrong status code(Below Screenshot is given). [image]

Here is a question that I think kind of what I am looking for [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701226/asp-net-mvc-406-not-acceptable-on-return-view). But I could not use CreateResponse in .NET 5.0 which I am currently working with.

Thank You.

Comment: You should not return an HttpResponseMessage from your .NET Core controller. As you can see in the response, MVC is simply serializing that .NET class to the output, because it has no special meaning to it, it's a class used by the "old" Web API and HttpClient.

Comment: So, Which class should be used in the new .NET Core controller & .NET 5/6.

Comment: See @jegtugado's answer below: `(I)ActionResult(<T>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return status codes using the following:

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable);

return new ObjectResult("Some message or object") { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable };
```

Comment: Will the return type of the controller be IActionResult and ActionResult? I thought action is only used during MVC can it be used during API as well. 1 more thing I wanted to know. In Get when you want to return object from the controller which is better to do? Return using ObjectResult or Return the object or list directly.

Comment: This approach will be available for IActionResult. You can use it on APIs as well. The only result exclusive for MVC are `PartialViewResult`, `ViewResult` and `ViewComponentResult`. `IActionResult` is the abstraction that allows us to return different results such as `FileResult`. ASP.NET Core supports returning both objects and IActionResults but based on experience IActionResult is better as it is abstracted. You want abstractions so that your code can be flexible and scalable.

Comment: Just clarifying your point(So that I do not mistake).  Api basically supports both IActionResults and its abstract class ActionResults and Any classes that implements them. Except for the implementations that returns Views. And since IActionResults is the abstraction on all the classes its better to use it because it will decouple the codes. That's about the gist of it I guess. Thank you, Really appreciate it. Was doing it wrong for a long time.

Comment: @KevinStephenBiswas your understanding is correct. If you look at the parent class that the MVC controller uses which is `Controller`, inside it implements `BaseController` which is the class you use when making API controllers in .NET